# Is it possible to create a file that when read, it runs a command to generate output?

Tags: macos, shell, unix

I'd like to create a file, for example lets call it `/tmp/not_running_pods`, that when read `cat /tmp/not_running_pods` runs `kubectl get pods -o wide | grep -v Running` and gives the output to the reading process.

This use case is simplified for example's sake. Not really looking for alternatives, unless it fits this exact case: file that outputs without having a 'service' always running listening for readers

Having a hard time finding anything specific for this on searching. My local env is macos, but hoping for something generalizable to linux/bash/zsh

edit: finally found what was on the tip of my brain, something like [inetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) / [super-server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super-server) - still looking to see if this would work for this case

Comment: Sounds like you want a fifo

Comment: Maybe `inetd` (or `systemd`?) with a UNIX domain socket.

Comment: Why don't you just do this the RIGHT way, and make that file a two-line shell script that you run instead of read?  It's silly to run a service 24/7 for what is essentially a macro.

Comment: inetd doesn't expose content _as a regular file_ (and the same is true for modern alternatives like systemd socket units). Can you have it run an arbitrary program when something connects to a socket? Absolutely. Can that be a UNIX named socket? Yes. Will that named socket act like a regular file? No; one has to `send()` and `recv()` data over it instead of being able to `read()` and `write()`, so you end up needing to run a tool like `socat` instead of `cat` to read from it, so why not just explicitly run your script as a subprocess?

Comment: BTW, none of this is something shell features can change, so there's no reason to tag a bunch of shells in this question (and in general, we frown on people tagging tools they think might possibly be used in an answer, as opposed to tools their question is _actually about_). UNIX semantics are what they are, and software (including shells) is limited to what the OS and kernel allow.

Comment: (both MacOS and Linux _do_ allow userspace filesystems, at least with a 3rd-party kext in the former, but writing a FUSE filesystem is not for the faint-of-heart, and not something that can be reasonably implemented as a shell script).

Comment: (btw, Apple's launchd does have its own superserver support, so you shouldn't need xinetd there either).

Comment: What is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? We could give you better answers if you told us what you're trying to accomplish and why simply running a script won't suffice. As written this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), where Y is "run a command when somebody reads a file". What is X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when read cat /tmp/not_running_pods **runs**

A file is static. It exists.

HTTP web servers **runs** a php script (and much more stuff) to generate the web page for you to view. An SSHD server **runs** a shell for you to connect with. MYSQL server serves a specific protocol that allows to execute queries.  To "do something" when a connection is made typically sockets - network, tcp, but also file sockets - are used, that allow with `accept()` detect incoming connections and **run** actually an action on such event.

```
# in one terminal
$ f() { echo new >&2; echo Hello world; LC_ALL=C date; }; export -f f; socat UNIX-LISTEN:/tmp/file,fork SYSTEM:'bash -c f'
new
new

# in the second terminal
$ socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/file -
Hello world
Tue Jul 19 21:29:03 CEST 2022
$ socat UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/file -
Hello world
Tue Jul 19 21:29:19 CEST 2022
```

If you *really* want to "execute an action when reading from a file", then you have to create your own *file system* that does that. Primary examples are files in `/proc` `/sys`. For user space file systems, write a program using FUSE.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
$ cat /tmp/not_running_pods
```

just make ~/bin/not_running_pods:

```
#! /bin/bash
kubectl get pods -o wide | grep -v Running
```

with `chmod 755` and do

```
$ not_running_pods
```

Easy, well-understood, well-supported.

Comment: This is very true, and very much good practice, but it's also pretty explicitly not what the OP is asking for.

Comment: As an experienced question answerer, I'm sure you know that what people ask for is very often not what they need.  It is the "bigger problem" conundrum.